# How can you set Skype for Business status when in a Teams call automatically?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams, skype-for-business

I've hit a wall so I'm asking my favorite community. I created custom Skype for Business activity statuses for Teams so when you are in a Teams call, you can manually set your status in SfB to "In a Teams Call". After searching for many days, i still have not found a way to auto set this status. Is there maybe a plugin for SfB or a service to run for this feature? This is for SfB (On-Prem). I primarily script in PowerShell but any guidance would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

@John, Microsoft Teams replaces Skype for Business Online as Microsoft’s professional online meeting solution. For more information on this please check this [document](https://www.skype.com/en/business/).

To get/set up user status, you can use Presence Graph API's. For more information on Presence Graph API, please check this [API docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

Answer (score 0):

I created a windows service to check my Teams presence using the Graph API. If it returns InACall, I use Skype for Business Modules to set my activity to In-A-Call.

Sample code:
https://schmalhorstorg.blogspot.com/2020/04/powershell-set-skype-for-business.html